# Node.js Less compiler parse error when #zoom: 1; used

Tags: css, node.js, less, dojo

I get a node less compiler error whenever the .less file has "#" hashtags being used in some situations. It seems to be ok with color hex values such as color: #FFFFFF; but you take something like #zoom: 1; and it blows up with a parseError for unrecognized input.

I'm not able to find any other postings directly related to the use of # and it tripping up the compiler so it makes me wonder why no one else is running into this problem.

Here is an actual example less file definition for a class taken from the Dojo SDK file dijit.css. I changed the extension to .less so I could combine it and other less files into one .css file:

```
.dijitInline {
/*  To inline block elements.
    Similar to InlineBox below, but this has fewer side-effects in Moz.
    Also, apparently works on a DIV as well as a FIELDSET.
*/
display:inline-block;           /* webkit and FF3 */
#zoom: 1; /* set hasLayout:true to mimic inline-block */
#display:inline; /* don't use .dj_ie since that increases the priority */
border:0;
padding:0;
vertical-align:middle;
#vertical-align: auto;  /* makes TextBox,Button line up w/native counterparts on IE6 */
}
```

The compiler chokes on the #zoom and #display lines.

Answer (score 1):

Technicaly speeking the `#zoom` is invalid css, though it is interpreted by IE and therefore often used as a IE fix solution. I suspect however that this is the reason why your compiler fails on it.

I work with the folowing inline-block mixin, which compiles fine in codekit and winless:

```
.display-inline-block() {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

The `*display` is just as invalid as your `#zoom` but my compiler does not seem to care. I did not try it with the `#`, but using the `*` in stead seems worth a shot...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have found places that do use the * instead of the # for display or zoom attributes. What does it mean in either case? i.e. what is the literal interpretation for those two symbols? The # usually means hex value or id attribute label. But how does IE interpret #?

Comment: The hashtag is indead used for hex color values. When it is placed in front of a style definition however, it is used as a 'IE hack'. There is plenty of information out there, like this blog post for example: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/